# Pattern for class instantiation from only one single place?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, class-design

C# .Net 4.0

I'd like to know how I can have a class which can only be instantiated from one single place. An example:

I've got a **Provider** class. This class exposes a method called **GetData**. When **GetData** is called, the **Provider** will instanciate a **Data** class, populate and return it. The **Data** class cannot be instanciated by anybody different then the **Provider**, so the only way to access the data will be through the **Provider**. Once **GetData** is called and a caller has received the **Data** class instance, he should be able to access properties/methods of this class.

How can this be done? Is there a pattern for this sort of problem? A short sample would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sort of solution design may be known as inversion of control. You may find an architecture already exists to build from, without writing from scratch. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_patternobjects.):

> The factory pattern is a creational
>   design pattern used in software
>   development to encapsulate the
>   processes involved in the creation of
>   objects.

Basically your `Provider` class is the factory that controlls the creation of instances of the `Data` class.

One thing you could do control this would be to place these two types in their own assembly and make the constructor for `Data` be `internal` but the class itself `public`.  This would mean that anyone who references the assembly would be forced to use the `Provider` class to create instances of `Data` (unless they used reflection, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually thought of a solution with multiple assemblies, but that would be a too big burger for this small project. Do you have an easy example on how to implement this pattern with everything being in the same assembly?

Answer (score 6):

Another solution would be to create an interface `IData`, and declare the `Provider.GetData` method to return `IData` instead of `Data`. Then you can have your `Data` class nested inside `Provider`. This way your `Data` class cannot be instantiated even by classes in the same assembly. Here is an example:

```
public interface IData
{
    // properties and methods
}

public class Provider
{
    public IData GetData()
    {
        return new Data();
    }

    private class Data : IData
    {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what Andrew described:

```
public class Data
{
    internal Data()
    {
        // internal constructor cannot be called from outside the assembly
    }

    // properties, fields and methods
}

public class Provider
{
    public Data GetData()
    {
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Provider
{
  protected Provider()
  {
  }

  public static Provider CreateNewProvider()
  {
    return new Provider();
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to know how to declare the `Data` class, not the `Provider` class!

Comment: Ah my mistake for not reading the question properly. Is that the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Yes, as it is misleading with regards to the OP's question.